# How to get Only Part of speech From POS_TAG in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, nltk, wordnet, pos-tagger

Hi every body I wan to get Pos_tag only like "jj" etc of a word . how to get this from list of  post_tag . 
I am able to print this result :

```
list1=nltk.pos_tag(words)
print(list1)
>>[('good', 'JJ')]
```

Now My question is now to separate word and post tag from the above result list.
I want to store word in myword variable and jj to mypos variable
**Please store good and jj into two different variable and print separate**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need this:

```
myword = list[0][0]
mypos = list[0][1]
```

Output:

```
good
JJ
```

Comment: Hi #Trollster one more question ,  How to separate name and middle english from this object  "  [Word(name, Middle English (1100-1500) [enm])]  " in python  . Get name in separate variable and after comma to another variable . means split this object into array that is inside ( ..) with comma ,